# Squid kerberos authentication

Tags: active-directory, centos, kerberos, squid

I am running a squid proxy server (CentOS 5) that I am trying to get working with kerberos through our AD server (Windows Server 2008).

I have followed the instructions here: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Kerberos

To setup a keytab for the server, which has all worked perfectly.

The problem occurs when I attempt to use the proxy from a client PC, where it immediately falls back to basic authentication.

If I use the ip address of the proxy I receive this message in cache.log:

> authenticateNegotiateHandleReply: Error validating user via Negotiate. Error returned 'BH     received type 1 NTLM token'

If I use the domain name of the proxy I receive this message in cache.log:

> authenticateNegotiateHandleReply: Error validating user via Negotiate. Error returned 'BH gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Configuration file does not specify default realm'

If I run klist on the client it has a ticket for the proxy server listed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need specify spn in the helper inside `squid.conf`
With the `-s http/fqdn@REALM`